# Different current folders in Debug and Run modes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have python code in Visual Studio Code :

```
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
print (current_working_directory)
```

It prints my Windows home directory when I run it. In case I do debug it prints folder where code file is located. Why? How to make the same behavior in both cases?

Comment: `__file__` is the path to the file that you use it in. You could likely use that in a clever way to always get the proper directory. ex:  in `some folder/main.py` - `print(__file__)  # path/to/some folder/main.py`

Comment: What is your directory structure? Have you configured the `cwd` parameter in *launch.json*?